An interesting integer classification and counting problem
Let
$$
\Omega:=\{a_0+a_14+\cdots+a_k4^k:\;a_i\in\{0,1\},\;0\leq i\leq k,\;k\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$
be a subset of natural numbers. For any integer $n\geq1$, define the counting function
$$
J(n):=\#\{j:\;j\in\Omega\;{\rm and}\; j\leq n\}
$$
as the number of elements that $\leq n$ and belong to the set $\Omega$. For example, if $n_1=1+4^2+4^5$ and $n_2=1+2\times4^2+4^5$, then $J(n_1)=1+2^2+2^5$ and $J(n_2)=1+2+2^2+2^5$.
$\color{blue}{\bf \large My\; question\; is:}$ Is there a constant $C>0$ such that, for all positive integers $n>0$ and $m>0$,
$$
J(n+m)-J(n)\leq CJ(m)
$$
holds true?
$$-----------------------------$$
In fact, through simple calculations, we have obtained the following estimate. For any integer $4^k\leq n<4^{k+1}$, $k\geq 0$, it is easy to see that
$2^k\leq J(n) \leq 1+2+\cdots+2^k= 2^{k+1}-1$
and then
$$
\frac 12 n^{1/2}\leq J(n)\leq 2n^{1/2}.
$$
By substituting this result into our problem, we have
$$
J(n+m)-J(n)\leq 2(n+m)^{1/2}-\frac 12m^{1/2},
$$
but this is not the estimate we were aiming for.

Please stop closing frenzy ! On which basis should this question be closed ?

@ Jean Marie  Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you meant. Did I edit the question too many times?

This remark wasn't addressed to you at all ; its target is a person advising to close your question without understandable reasons.

1/ Note the typo in the last equation. 2/ You could show that $J(n) \approx \sqrt{n}$ (and bound accordingly), which naively yields a $ C \approx 1$ as a candidate, so it should be possible that $ C < 2$ (or loosen as needed).

I think this is true.
Let $a = a_0 + a_1 4 + a_2 4^2 + \cdots$ be the smallest element in $J \cap (n,  n+ m]$, and $b = a_0 + a_1 4 + a_2 4^2 + \cdots$ be the largest element in $J \cap (n,  n+ m]$. Let $k$ be the largest integer of $a_k \neq b_k$. Then we can form the following estimate on $m$
$$m \geq b - a = \sum_{i = 1}^k (b_k - a_k) \cdot 4^i \geq 4^k - 4^{k - 1} - \cdots - 1 \geq 2 \cdot 4^{k - 1}.$$
Thus we have
$$J(m) \geq m^{1/2} / 2 \geq 2^{k - 1}.$$
On the other hand, any element $c = c_0 + c_1 4 + c_2 4^2 + \cdots$ in $J \cap (n,  n+ m]$ must satisfy $c_{j} = a_j = b_j$ for any $j > k$. Furthermore, we must have $c_i \in \{0, 1\}$ for $i = 0,1,\cdots,k$. Thus, the number of possible $c$ is at most $2^{k + 1}$. So we have
$$J(n + m) - J(n) \leq 2^{k + 1}.$$
Combining, we have
$$J(n + m) - J(n) \leq 4 J(m).$$
